# Assembly Language loops

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm bumping into a little bit of troubles trying to get my loop to work properly. Here's what I need to do

Add 3 to i1 and store the result into i1
 Multiply i2 by 3 and store the result into i2

Terminate the loop if either i1 becomes greater than 100 OR if both the following are true: more than 15 iterations of the loop have occurred AND i2 has reached a value of at least 999999.

It's not finished yet, but I was wondering is it possible to use 2 CMP in a loop?
Here's what I have so far:

```
        {
unsigned long i1;
unsigned long i2;
unsigned long i3;
unsigned long i4;
_asm
    {
    mov     i1, 1
    mov     i2, 1
    mov     eax, i1
    mov     ebx, i2
    mov     ecx, 3
Start:
    add     eax, ecx
    cmp     eax, 100
    jnz     Start
    jge     Done


Start2:
    imult   ebx, ecx
    cmp     ebx, 999999



Done:
    mov     i1, eax
    }
    cout << "results are "  << (unsigned long) i1 << ", "
                            << (unsigned long) i2 << ", "
                            << (unsigned long) i3 << ", "
                            << (unsigned long) i4 << endl;

}
```

Comment: There are no loops in x86 assembly, only conditional branches and a couple of special instructions that can be auto-repeated. Loops are just a way you think of your code, the code doesn't know about them. Therefore, there can be no limitations to what you could do in a loop. Even the instruction `loop` does not loop, it's just a decrement-and-branch-if-not-zero - it can branch forwards just as well as backwards.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `cmp` in two different procedures (not loops, as @harold mentions). You'll probably want some kind of jump after the `cmp` in `Start2`, otherwise you'll just fall back to `Done`.  But, based on the `999999` immediate, it looks like that is the intent.  So, you can perform a jump back to the "loop" if you have not yet reached that value.  Otherwise, if you reach that value, proceed to `Done`.

Comment: The `jge` is fine too. `cmp \ jcc` are not a "pair", `jcc` just looks at the flags (and doesn't change them) and `cmp` is nothing more than a `sub` that doesn't destroy the first operand.

Comment: @harold: Where's `jcc`?  Or do you mean `jnz`?

Comment: Any j-something (except `jmp` obviously). `cc` stands for condition-code.

Comment: @harold: Ah, I see.  So, is that part of my answer (with `jge`) incorrect, or the entire thing?